# Check if a passed double argument is "close enough" to be considered integral

Tags: c++, rounding-error

I am working on a code where I need to check if a certain variable that can take a double value has actually taken on an integer value. I consider a double variable to have taken on an integer value if it is within a tolerance of an integer. This tolerance is 1e-5.

The following is my code:

```
#define SMALL 1e-5
//Double that attains this is considered non zero. Strictly Less than this is 0

int check_if_integer(double arg){
//returns 1 if arg is close enough to an integer
//returns 0 otherwise
    if(arg - (int)arg >= SMALL){
        if(arg + SMALL > (int)(arg+1.0)){
            return(1);
//Code should have reached this point since
//arg + SMALL is 16.00001 
//while (int)(arg+1.0) should be 16
//But the code seems to evaluate (int)(arg+1.0) to be 17
        }
    }
    else{
        return(1);
    }
    return(0);
}

int main(void){

    int a = check_if_integer(15.999999999999998);

}
```

Unfortunately, on passing the argument 15.999999999999998, the function returns a 0. That is, it deems the argument to be fractional, while it should have returned a 1 indicating that the argument is "close enough" to 16.

I am using VS2010 professional.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, floating point is hard. Just because `15.999999999999998 < 16.0`, that doesn't mean `15.999999999999998 + 1.0 < 17.0`. Suppose you have a decimal floating-point type with three digits of precision. What result do you get for `9.99 + 1.0` in that type's precision? The mathematical result would be `10.99`, and rounded to that type's precision gives `11.0`. Binary floating-point has the same issue.

You can, in this particular case, change `(int)(arg+1.0)` to `(int)arg+1`. `(int)arg` is accurate, and so is integer addition.

Comment: Your suggestion works in my case and fits into the current code I have.

Answer (score 4):

Further to hvd's answer regarding types; it is also inadvisable to add/subtract small doubles to/from large doubles due to the way in which they are internally represented.

A simple work around which avoids both issues would be:

```
if (abs(arg - round(arg)) <= SMALL) {
  return (1);
} else {
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: It appears that round is not available in VS2010. https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/270269/boss_loken-cpp147-error-c3861-round-identifier-not-found but I have a workaround it as specified in that link. Your code works fine. Thanks.